# android sdk build tools 25 on centos 6.8 error

Tags: android, linux, jenkins, glibc

I'm using `jenkins` for CI and after updating my build tools version to 25 I got this error:

```
 "processReleaseResources/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt)"
```

I need to use buildtools 25 and my server centos version is 6.8. 
How can I update `glibc` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the program you are trying to use was not compiled for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (which only provides glibc 2.12, and not version 2.14 or later, which seems to be needed here).  You either have to recompile it on that version of the operating system, or upgrade to a later version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux.